# Laptop gets hot but CPU and GPU utilisation stats show near-zero usage

Tags: cpu, fan

Until recently my laptop under Ubuntu wasn't even starting fan. Now, while idle it makes quite a lot of noise and feels hot under the keyboard. I have i7-1165G7 and Mesa Intel® Xe Graphics (TGL GT2). I checked htop and intel_gpu_top and both show cpu/gpu utilisation under 1%. I checked the system monitor, no signs of CPU load too. The laptop is 4 months old, and shouldn't have a lot of dust, still vacuumed just in case.

Any ideas on how to approach this situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hardware problem?

Comment: If this is a dual boot laptop, check if the same thing happens with Windows. Also boot from a Live Ubuntu installation USB using the **Try Ubuntu** option, and see if the same thing happens. If it happens with a live USB, it is probably a hardware problem. Contact the manufacturer for replacement of service under warranty.

Comment: I have a similar problem and not yet solved it. I don't have hard stats to back it up and can't even remember now which Ubuntu version caused the issue but I have Conky running and I know that older versions of Ubuntu my CPU/cores/ACPI temps were always below 60c at idle. After an Ubuntu upgrade with no other changes I noticed higher temps straight away. Today with 22.04.1 LTS all temps are fairly constantly 60-70c at idle with no apps running. No high cpu/mem usage. HP OMEN 15-5000na i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz × 8 NV117 / Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)

Comment: Thanks, guys! Will try the suggested.